# Invalid Access Token: Display Spotify Profile in Web App Tutorial

Tags: http, access-token, spotify

I'm currently following this tutorial on the Spotify website:
https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/howtos/web-app-profile

The code is simply supposed to redirect you to the Spotify login page where you input your credentials, agree to give your info to my app (accept terms), and then your User ID, email, spotify URI, profile link, and profile image is displayed on the page.

On the `getAccessToken` function, I'm getting a POST 400 error.
On the fetchProfile function, I'm getting a GET 401 error.
The console also displays the message:

> "Invalid Access Token."

Here is my code for `getAccessToken`:

```
export async function getAccessToken(clientId, code) {
    const verifier = localStorage.getItem("verifier");

    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append("client_id", clientId);
    params.append("grant_type", "authorization_code");
    params.append("code", code);
    params.append("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:5173/callback");
    params.append("code_verifier", verifier);

    const result = await fetch("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
        body: params
    });

    const { access_token } = await result.json();
    return access_token;
}
```

Here is my code for `fetchProfile`:

```
async function fetchProfile(token){
    const result = await fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me", {
        method: "GET", headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
    });

    return await result.json();
}
```

All of the ports are correct and I have the correct URI in my Development Dashboard. I've tried adding a CORS mode in the result variable, I cleared my cache, tried another port, etc. I'm new to this and at a complete loss, so if anyone has any solutions that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Authorization Code` Flow in Spotify needs a server feature on the application side.

It can get code value from Spotify server, then request a token with code.

In the `code flow` diagram, explain detail [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/code-flow)

[image]

This code will work

Save as `get-token.js`

```js
const express = require("express")
const axios = require('axios')
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express()
app.use(cors())

CLIENT_ID = "<your client id>"
CLIENT_SECRET = "<your client secret>"
PORT = 5173 // it is located in Spotify dashboard's Redirect URIs, my port is 3000
REDIRECT_URI = `http://localhost:${PORT}/callback` // my case is 'http://localhost:3000/callback'
SCOPE = [
    "user-read-email",
    "playlist-read-collaborative"
]

app.get("/login", (request, response) => {
    const redirect_url = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&scope=${SCOPE}&state=123456&redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}&prompt=consent`
    response.redirect(redirect_url);
})

app.get("/callback", async (request, response) => {
    const code = request.query["code"]
    await axios.post(
        url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
        data = new URLSearchParams({
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'redirect_uri': REDIRECT_URI,
            'code': code
        }),
        config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            params: {
                'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
            },
            auth: {
                username: CLIENT_ID,
                password: CLIENT_SECRET
            }
        })
        .then(resp1 => {
            return response.send(JSON.stringify(resp1.data));
        });

})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on :${PORT}`)
})
```

`Scopes` need to add depends on your API call.
Detail information in [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/concepts/scopes).

#### Steps

##### #1 Install dependencies

```
npm install express axios cors
```

##### #2 Run Application

```
node get-token.js
```

##### #3 Open Browser and access this URL

```
http://localhost:5173/login
```

##### #4 Login with your Spotify credential.

This login screen automatically shows to you.

[image]

##### Result

In my case port is 3000

[image]

Comment: good to hear, you got it, don't forget accept my answer. you can do even if less 15 point. If you click up green arrow from my answer, it will give me 15 points, thanks!

Comment: Okay! I hit the green arrow let me know if it went through!